# Foreach through a list - duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This seems such a basic issue, however, I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a list of 'FavouritePost', which contains 'FavId', UserId and a PostId. This class is used to determine if a user has added a post to a 'favourite' list. In my controller I filter out the posts, only selecting the post's which match the current userId. In my view I have the following foreach loop:

```
@foreach (var fav in Model.FavPosts)
{
    if (post.PostId == fav.PostId)
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/favourite_img.jpg")" alt="" />
    }
    else if (post.PostId != fav.PostId)
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Notfavourite_img.jpg")" alt="" />
    }
}
```

My problem is this: When the foreach loop runs it displays an image next to the post, based on whether the user has 'liked' that post. However, when I run the following code it assigns multiple images next to the post. For instance, based on the following table data:

```
FavId      UserId      PostId

  1          1           1
  2          1           2
  3          1           4
```

UserId = 1, has liked three posts (1,2,4), however, UserId = 1 has not 'liked' post 3

However, when I run my page, for the first post, 3 images are displayed.

```
Post 1 = "Liked Image", "Not Liked Image", "Not Liked Image"
Post 2 = "Not Liked Image", "Liked Image", "Not Liked Image"
Post 2 = "Not Liked Image", "Not Liked Image", "Liked Image"
```

It seems to be iterating through three times, and assigning three images to the post, rather than one image. I realise it's because of the number of UserId in the list, however, I thought the condtional statement would stop the alternative image from displaying. Apologies for the verbose question, I just thought it would make it easier to unserstand my dilemma. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you show where your model is being setup? the Linq query is what i'm interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing something along these lines:

```
@if (Model.FavPosts.Any(x => x.PostId == post.PostId))
    // show favourite icon
else
    // show not favourite icon
```

Or, if equality on your `Post` class is defined using the `PostId`, might be able to do this for (arguably) improved readability:

```
@if (Model.FavPosts.Contains(post))
    // show favourite icon
else
    // show not favourite icon
```

What you're doing right now is checking on each post in `FavPost` to see if it matches, and outputting the info each time.  It's not smart enough to know what you really meant, it's just doing what you told it.  Similar to how the following code would write 2 nopes and a yep:

```
int[] favorites = { 1, 2, 3 };
int thisOne = 3;
foreach (var fav in favorites)
{
   if (thisOne == fav)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("yep");
   }
   else if (thisOne != fav)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("nope");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tim S, thanks for nice explantion. It has solved the issue of the printing of both images, however, it still seems to print out three images, rather than one. Would I need to add a count to my foreach statement?

Comment: It shouldn't be `foreach (var fav in Model.FavPosts) { if (Model.FavPosts.Any...` but simply `if (Model.FavPosts.Any...`. If this doesn't help, please give more detail by editing your question to show your current code.

Comment: Removed the foreach loop and it worked. Thank you so much Tim for your help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
@if(Model.FavPosts.Where(f => post.PostId == f.PostId).Any())
{
     <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/favourite_img.jpg")" alt="" />
}
else
{
     <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Notfavourite_img.jpg")" alt="" />
}
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if a post has an entry in the FavPost list. If it has an entry output the favourite image, of not the Notfavourite image.